# How to call-by-reference a variable of one class from another in C++

Tags: c++, oop, class

I have a class, let's call it `class A`, that is performing a calculation which returns a value of `int value`, and another class in my system, `class B` needs to use `int value` for further calculations. My plan is to use a third class, `class C`, where the variable will be defined, to pass the variable between A and B, with these two just working from references to the `int value` in `class C`. My problem is I don't know how to reference a variable in another class without first instantiating some class or another, with the ensuing construction potentially overwriting `int value`.

---

**Update**: The code below outlines what I'm trying to achieve. I'm am trying to have  variable

```
class A
{
public:
    void calculation1()
};

void A::calculation1()
{
    value = 10;
}

class B
{
public:
    void calculation2();
};

void B::calculation2()
{
    for (int count = 0; count < value; count ++)
    {
        // Do stuff here
    }
}

class C
{
    int value;
}
```

Comment: Add real code so we can solve your real problem, please. "Let's say" can only get answer of the same type.

Comment: I've added some code to my question. It isn't much because my problem is that I don't know what I'm supposed to be writing for this.

Comment: Why do A, B, and C need to be classes?  What's stopping you from doing `B(A(...))` where A and B are plain old functions?

Comment: This is just a skeleton of what the program's eventually going to look like. I'm just right now learning about OOP and am trying to figure out how classes are supposed to communicate results of calculations between each other, before I start coding, so I can incorporate that into the design.

Comment: @Chris: Keep in mind OOP isn't the be all and end all solution to programming; in fact, it's quite an ugly solution for many problems. It's just a tool, and if you don't need it don't use it. If your calculations don't operate on *encapsulated data members*, then they don't need to be member functions. Prefer free-functions to member-functions.

Comment: @GMan I'm going to take your advice and re-assess the problem. Glancing over it, it looks as if I can easily remove several of the classes and just make them free-functions. I'd gotten to wrapped up in trying to design the program around OOP (use of classes is what's being assessed) that I forgot I could have free-functions. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you're not going in the right direction here. If I rephrase your problem description in pseudo-code, I get something like :

```
// The second calculation result depends on the result of the first one, so we
// provide it as a parameter.
int firstValue = calculationA();
int secondValue = calculationB(firstValue);
```

This is perfectly valid in itself : you just have to implement two free functions `calculationA` and `calculationB` and there is no need for classes of anything like it. Now, if you *really* want to put classes around this, you can.

What you need to understand is that classes interaction are a consequence of their respective responsibilities, not the opposite. For example, if the result of `calculation1` has absolutely no utility beside being fed to `calculation2`, maybe the two functions shouldn't belong to different classes. Identify the responsibilities, try to express them as classes, and the interaction will appear naturally.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just have a `set` function in `class B`, where you can set the value to what the calculation in `A` returns?

Comment: What is a `set` function? I've been looking around both textbooks and the internet and I can't find any reference to a generic function such as `set()`, except more questions about them. I've found specific functions, like `setSize()`, but that's it.

Comment: @Chris: You *make* it, it doesn't exist until you do.